# Some issues with jumping from one function to another in a loop in php

Tags: php

i noticed a wired behavior of php when doing something like

the code below is trying to loop through all arrays in multiarray, and it it should return $n when it is not an array anymore.
basicly a counter for dimentions.

```
<?php 
//some random values multiarray
$arrays[1][2][3][5] = '1';
$arrays[1][2][3] = '1';
$arrays[1][2][3][4] = '1';
$arrays[3][6][3][1][5] = '2';

function second_func($array, $n)//adding $n then returning to 1st func
{
    $n++;
    first_func($array, $n);
}
function first_func($arrays, $n = 0)//checking if array then 2nd func, if not then return.
{
    if(is_array($arrays))
    { 
        foreach($arrays as $array)second_func($array, $n); 
    }else
    {
        echo $n; //working
        return $n; //not working
    };
}
$result[] = first_func($arrays);
print_r($result);//nothing here
```

or any similar actions, if i put file_put_contents inside 1st function, then the result will be different with each refresh, and the function cannot be returned just as it is, only echoing it works stable.

I remember i had a similar 2 function to delete cache files and ended up with clean hard drive, or a similar func to create file and i would have files in random folders over hd.

didnt check for similar quastions, cannot formulate the quastion right..

Comment: [Comments archived in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/154016/discussion-on-question-by-leo-tahk-some-issues-with-jumping-from-one-function-to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the `first_func` function does not always return a value, only when the argument is not an array. But since you call it initially with an array argument, *that* particular call will not return anything, and this explains the blank output you get. So, even when you call a function recursively (via `second_func`), you must still return something.

If I understand correctly, you want an output per "leaf" in the tree of nested arrays: for each leaf, its depth in the tree should be output.

Here is how you could do that:

```
function first_func($arrays, $n = 0) {
    if(is_array($arrays)) {
        $result = [];
        foreach($arrays as $array)
            $result = array_merge($result, first_func($array, $n+1));
    } else {
        $result = [$n];
    }
    return $result;
}
```

This will return an array of integers, where each integer represents the depth of a particular leaf in the data.

Note that I removed `second_func`, as it is quite trivial. Writing `first_func($arrays, $n+1)` is not less clear than `second_func($array, $n)`. If however you want to keep `second_func`, then make sure to *return* a value:

```
function second_func($array, $n) {
    $n++;
    return first_func($array, $n);
}
```

For this data:

```
$arrays = [
    1 => [
        2 => [
            3 => "1   1"
        ]
    ],
    3 => [
        6 => [
            3 => [
                1 => [
                    5 => "2"
                ]
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

... the above code will return:

```
[3, 5]
```

Which can be formatted as 35 with:

```
echo implode("", first_func($arrays));
```

Comment: your code works correct, its a good count dimentions function. My main quastion was why i get bugged with double functions. I guess its the "empty returns". Was one of the reasons i deleted my entire HardDrive before. Thanks for your time.