# Checking if previous nodes of an array exist

Tags: php

I am trying to get it so that the output that is as follows (currently):

```
┌── Level 0 Child 1
└── Level 0 Child 2
|   ├── Level 1 Child 1
|   |   └── Level 1 Child 1 Grandchild 1
|   └── Level 1 Child 2
|   |   ├── Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1
|   |   |   ├── Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 1
|   |   |   ├── Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 2
|   |   |   └── Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 3
|   |   └── Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 2
|   |   |   └── Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 2 Great-grandchild 1
```

to be correct.

Obviously, the actual outcome i want is where not every square has the vertical lines, if that node has already reached its end of the line `└──`.

This is my current code:

```
function makeList(array $array, $level = 0, $very_first_item = true)
{
    $output = "\n";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $subArray) {
        if($count == count($array) - 1) {
            $prefix = str_repeat('|   ', $level) . '└── ';
        } elseif($very_first_item === true) {
            $prefix =  str_repeat('|   ', $level) . '┌── ';
        } else {
            $prefix = str_repeat('|   ', $level) . '├── ';
        }
        $very_first_item = false;
        $output .= $prefix . $key . makeList($subArray, $level + 1, $very_first_item);
        $count++;
    }

    return $output;
}
```

This is the array to be passed in:

```
array(
    'Level 0 Child 1' =>
        array(),
    'Level 0 Child 2' =>
        array(
            'Level 1 Child 1' =>
                array(
                    'Level 1 Child 1 Grandchild 1' =>
                        array(),
                ),
            'Level 1 Child 2' =>
                array(
                    'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1' =>
                        array(
                            'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 1' =>
                                array(),
                            'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 2' =>
                                array(),
                            'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 3' =>
                                array(),
                        ),
                    'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 2' =>
                        array(
                            'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 2 Great-grandchild 1' =>
                                array(),
                        ),
                ),
        ),
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this code can help you.

I have changed your `makeList` function, also added another function with the name of `array_depth` which calculates the depth of your array using [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is) and also added another node to the end of your array to check if the code is working properly. so, here's the code:

```
$myArr = array(
    'Level 0 Child 1' => array(),
    'Level 0 Child 2' => array(
        'Level 1 Child 1' => array(
            'Level 1 Child 1 Grandchild 1' => array(),
        ),
        'Level 1 Child 2' => array(
            'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1' =>   array(
                'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 1' => array(),
                'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 2' => array(),
                'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 1 Great-grandchild 3' => array(),
            ),
            'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 2' => array(
                'Level 1 Child 2 Grandchild 2 Great-grandchild 1' => array(),
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'Level 0 Child 3' => array(
        'Level 1 Child 1' => array(
            'Level 1 Child 1 Grandchild 1' => array(),
        ),
    )
);

function array_depth(array $array){
    $max_depth = 1;

    foreach ($array as $value){
        if (is_array($value)){
            $depth = array_depth($value) + 1;

            if ($depth > $max_depth){
                $max_depth = $depth;
            }
        }
    }

    return $max_depth;
}


function makeList(array $array, $level = 0, $very_first_item = true)
{
    global $arrLines;
    $output = "\n";
    $count = 0;
    foreach ($array as $key => $subArray) {
        if($count == count($array) - 1) {
            $prefix = '└── ';
            $arrLines[$level + 1] = '    ';
        } elseif($very_first_item === true) {
            $prefix =  '┌── ';
            $arrLines[$level + 1] = '|   ';
        } else {
            $prefix = '├── ';
            $arrLines[$level + 1] = '|   ';
        }
        $very_first_item = false;
        for($iCnt = 1; $iCnt <= $level; $iCnt++)
            $output .=  $arrLines[$iCnt];
        $output .= $prefix . $key . makeList($subArray, $level + 1, $very_first_item);
        $count++;
    }

    return $output;
}

$arrLines = array(array_depth($myArr));
echo '<pre>'.makeList($myArr).'</pre>';
```

Comment: That looks fantastic. Thank you. :) What name or github link do you have so I can credit you for improving the code?

Comment: Thanks man, it's most generous of you. I do not have github account and the real work was done by "Jeremy Ruten" which had developed the `array_depth` function. have fun coding. :)

Comment: Please can you link to the array_depth so i can attribute it properly? thanks :)