# Array PHP. How to get deep of element in array

Tags: php, arrays

```
$mang = array(
            '0' => array(
                'uid' => 2,
                'introducer_uid' => 1,
                'introducer_users' => array(
                                        '0' => array(
                                                'uid' => 8,
                                                'introducer_uid' => 2,
                                                'introducer_users' => array() 
                                                ),
                                        '1' => array(
                                                'uid' => 9,
                                                'introducer_uid' => 2,
                                                'introducer_users' => array()) 
                                        ) 
                ),
            '1' => array(
                'uid' => 3,
                'introducer_uid' => 1,
                'introducer_users' => array(
                                        '0' => array(
                                                'uid' => 5,
                                                'introducer_uid' => 3,
                                                'introducer_users' => array()
                                        ),
                                        '1' => array(
                                                'uid' => 6,
                                                'introducer_uid' => 3,
                                                'introducer_users' => array() 
                                        ),
                                        '2' => array(
                                                'uid' => 7,
                                                'introducer_uid' => 3,
                                                'introducer_users' => array(
                                                                        '0' => array(
                                                                                    'uid' => 10,
                                                                                    'introducer_uid' => 7,
                                                                                    'introducer_users' => array(
                                                                                                            '0' => array(
                                                                                                                'uid' => 11,
                                                                                                                'introducer_uid' => 10,
                                                                                                                'introducer_users' => array() 
                                                                                                                        ) 
                                                                                                            ) 
                                                                                    ) 
                                                                        ) 
                                                ) 
                                        ) 
                ),
            '2' => array(
                    'uid' => 4,
                    'introducer_uid' => 1,
                    'introducer_users' => array() 
                ) 
        );
```

**My require:**

Make a functions to Count deep of item in $mang array.

**Sample.**
Deep of any item will return look like:

- 'uid' = 10  will return deep = 3
- 'uid' = 11  will return deep = 4
- 'uid' = 8  will return deep =  2
- 'uid' =  2  will return deep =  1

**Sample functions look like**

`function count_deep($array,$uid){ return $deep; }`

Anyone please help me. Thank you so much.

Comment: What would help is if you could tell us. How would you like to query your giant array and what would you like to return from said query?

Comment: `function count_deep($array,$uid){
   return $deep;
}`

Comment: If it is school task, and the array not that deep - recursive functions with depth count will do the job with almost no code.
your count_deep can call count_deep_rec($array, $uid, 0/*the initial depth*/, false/*is_found?*)

Is found can be used later to stop the other recursive calls if there are and improve perf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following recursive function to get the *depth* where the uuid value is found. This version returns value 0 if the uuid value is not found at all.

```
function searchDepth($uid, $array, $depth = 0)
{
    $depth++;

    foreach ($array as $element)
    {
        if (isset($element['uid']) && $element['uid'] == $uid)
        {
            return $depth;
        }
        else if (isset($element['introducer_users']))
        {
            $result = searchDepth($uid, $element['introducer_users'], $depth);

            if ($result != 0)
            {
                return $result;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And to invoke the function with the search uuid and the array

```
$depth = searchDepth(10, $mang);
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone has [already asked this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is). Best look for an answer there; however, note that in PHP it is possible to have an infinitely deep array, it would therefore be a good idea to have a maximum depth just in case things get ridiculous.

Comment: Thanks, i found this but it not help me.