# How to get maxium Levels for a Multidimensional array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a such array

```
 <?php 
    array( 
        'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
        array( 
            'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                array( 
                    'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                        array( 
                            'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                            )
                        )
                    )
               )
           )
        )
    ),
    array( 
        'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
            array( 
                'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    array( 
        'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
            array( 
                'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                    array( 
                        'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                            array( 
                                'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                                    array( 
                                        'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                                            array( 
                                                'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                                                    array( 
                                                        'CHILDRENS' =>  array(
                                                        )
                                                    )
                                                )
                                            )
                                        )
                                    )
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
```

I would like to know how to get the maxium deep of this array. 
I tried this :

[Array PHP. How to get deep of element in array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33103957/array-php-how-to-get-deep-of-element-in-array)

and

[Is there a way to find out how "deep" a PHP array is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is)

It that last case, it return only first array depth

Thanks for help.

Comment: Which of the many "last case" solutions exactly have you tried?

Comment: The provided solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/262944/4028339 doesn't work. This function count all the depth, i want to get count the array levels.

Comment: I finally found a solution by myself. <code>public function array_depth(array $array, $current_depth = 0) {
  global $depth;
  
  if( $array ) {
   foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
    // var_dump( $key );
    if ( is_array( @$value[ 'CHILDRENS' ] ) ) {
     $this->array_depth( $value[ 'CHILDRENS' ], $current_depth + 1 ); 
    } 
   }
  } else {
   if( intval( $depth ) < $current_depth ) {
    $depth  = $current_depth;
   }
  }
  
  return intval( $depth );
 }</code>