# php find item dimension in array

Tags: php, arrays

find items level(depth) in array;

hi im new in php and i cant find any method to find what dimension array items are in.
for example:

```
array=>[
  'name'=>'jack'
  , 'age'=>'18'
  , 'info'=>[
    'address'=>'bla bla bla'
    , 'email'=>'example@bla.com'
  ]
]
```

```
function findDepth($key)
{
  // do something
}

$result = findDepth('email');

$result // int(2)
```

the array above has key named email and the email key is in second level of the array.
is there any function or method or way to find this level.

I found a method that tell you how deep array is: [Is there a way to find out how "deep" a PHP array is?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/262891/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-how-deep-a-php-array-is)

Comment: Hi! Your question is a bit unclear. Can you give an example of the input you want to provide, and the output you want to get?

Comment: yes of course      .

Comment: No, there is none. Use recursive function to search for element and return it's depth

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using recursive function:

```php
<?php

$array = [
    'name'=>'jack', // Level 0
    'age'=>'18',
    'info'=>[ // Level 1
        'address'=>'bla bla bla',
        'contacts' => [ // Level 2
            'email'=>'example@bla.com'
        ],
    ],
];

function getArrayKeyDepth(array $array, $key, int $currentDepth = 0): ?int
{
    foreach($array as $k => $v){
        if ($key === $k) {
            return $currentDepth;
        }
        
        if (is_array($v)) {
            $d = getArrayKeyDepth($v, $key, $currentDepth + 1);
            
            if ($d !== null) {
                return $d;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return null;
}

echo "Result:  ". getArrayKeyDepth($array, 'email');
```

This will give you "Result: 2"

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function.

```php
function findDepth(array $array, string $key, int $level = 0) : ?int
{
    $level++;
    foreach($array as $k=>$row){
        if($k == $key) return $level;
        if(is_array($row) && $c = findDepth($row, $key, $level)) return $c;
    }
    return null;
}
```

This will return only the first key match so if you had another `email` key in the root of your array further down in the index, you would still only get `2` as the result.

Working sample: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3d5847fa8f67cd52f5f95eccefa75359a721edc0

Comment: hi yes thanx for your help .